# Batch rename of files - Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, command-line

Morning,

I would like to rename a number of files from `filename.outable` to `filename_Hole_1.txt` i.e. I need to append `_Hole_1` to each filename and changing the extension from `.outable` to `.txt`.

I nearly achieved this yesterday (I had a space I didn't want) but I can't find where I found the script from yesterday and I didn't write it down properly. What I have is:

```
for %a in (*.outable) do ren "%~a" "%~na _Hole_1.txt
```

Please can you help me fix this code and also help me understand how it works?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've nearly got it:

```dos
For %A In (*.outable) Do Ren "%A" "%~nA_Hole_1.txt"
```

Note the above code is for Command prompt entry, if you use it in a batch file then double up each percent character.

Comment: Thanks, why are you using uppercase and not lowercase "A"?

Comment: No reason other than I believe it stands out better.